# jQuery append function damage functionality

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-append

I am using [sb-admin-2 bootstrap template](https://github.com/IronSummitMedia/startbootstrap/tree/gh-pages/templates/sb-admin-2) ([template demo](http://startbootstrap.com/templates/sb-admin-2/)) for a simple project. I have a trouble with left side menu.

Here is default menu items code;

```
<div class="sidebar-nav navbar-collapse">
<ul class="nav" id="side-menu">
    <li>
        <a class="active" href="index.html"><i class="fa fa-dashboard fa-fw"></i> Dashboard</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o fa-fw"></i> Charts<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
        <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
            <li>
                <a href="flot.html">Flot Charts</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="morris.html">Morris.js Charts</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <!-- /.nav-second-level -->
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="tables.html"><i class="fa fa-table fa-fw"></i> Tables</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="forms.html"><i class="fa fa-edit fa-fw"></i> Forms</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-wrench fa-fw"></i> UI Elements<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
        <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
            <li>
                <a href="panels-wells.html">Panels and Wells</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="buttons.html">Buttons</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="notifications.html">Notifications</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="typography.html">Typography</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="grid.html">Grid</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <!-- /.nav-second-level -->
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-sitemap fa-fw"></i> Multi-Level Dropdown<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
        <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
            <li>
                <a href="#">Second Level Item</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Second Level Item</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Third Level <span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                <ul class="nav nav-third-level">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Third Level Item</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Third Level Item</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Third Level Item</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Third Level Item</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <!-- /.nav-third-level -->
            </li>
        </ul>
        <!-- /.nav-second-level -->
    </li>
    <%--
    <li>
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-files-o fa-fw"></i> Sample Pages<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
        <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
            <li>
                <a href="blank.html">Blank Page</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="login.html">Login Page</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <!-- /.nav-second-level -->
    </li>
     --%>
</ul>
```

It looks like this when menu item with submenus is opened: 
[image: opened menu]

It looks like this when menu item with submenus is closed: 
[image: closed menu]

When I make an ajax request for adding items to menu, it breaks the show/hide functionality of menu item. When I click arrow which is near to "Ajax loaded menu item", no event handled. Here is my code and screenshot of broken menu item;

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$.ajax({
    url     :   "/loadMenuItems",
    success :   function(result)
    {
        var menuList = result.menuList; 

        $.each(menuList, function(menuIndex, menuItem) {

            var newMenuItem =   '<li> ' +
                                '   <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-files-o fa-fw"></i>' + menuItem.itemHeader + '<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>' +
                                '   <ul class="nav nav-second-level"> ' +
                                '       <li> ' + 
                                '           <a href="blank.html">' + menuItem.item1 + '</a> ' +
                                '       </li> ' + 
                                '       <li> ' +
                                '           <a href="login.html">' + menuItem.item2 + '</a> ' + 
                                '       </li> ' +
                                '   </ul> ' +
                                '</li> ';

            $('#side-menu').append(newMenuItem);
        });
    }
});
});
```

[image: broken menu]

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `sb-admin-2.js` file of the template you have the following call for the Metis Menu Function, which enables the functionality you want.

```
$('#side-menu').metisMenu();
```

I don't know when you ajax call is made, but **after** you added the additional elements to the menu you have to make this metisMenu call (again).

Just put in in your ajax call, after the

> $('#side-menu').append(newMenuItem);

Maybe you have remove it from the `sb-admin-2.js` file. Experiment with it. But making the `$('#side-menu').metisMenu();` call after you attached the items is crucial for the functionality.

Comment: When I remove function call from related js file, than I put it after ajax call, it worked. Thx.